# Google map not showing exact address by putting latitude and longitude

Tags: php, google-maps

I know this question has been asked multiple times before but my situation is quite different. My code is in PHP. I am getting correct address but not exact. For example, when I put Latitude = 24.8369 and Longitude = 67.0334, I get address = Frere Town, Karachi, Pakistan. But it should fetch PSO Head Office, Karachi.

The reason I am able to comprehend is that my code is not zooming the address to its very exact location. Technically, PSO Head Office, Karachi in in Frere Town region. So, my code is pointing towards Frere town but I need it more detailed and specific. It should point PSO Head Office.

Please guide me to the right direction. Thank you

Comment: can you post pic of google map showing PSO Head Office?

Comment: When I get latitude and longitude from address, it is showing address but when I get address from latitude and longitude, it points me near PSO head office

Comment: reverse geocoding could return one or more results

Comment: please add your code to the question

Comment: Make sure that you haven't lost any decimals. The more decimals, the more accurate results. But as already pointed out, a single office can only have one location while one location can have multiple offices.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your intention is finding business by its coordinate. You are using the reverse geocoding service if I understand correctly. Please note that reverse geocoding is not designed to search businesses, it's designed to search nearest addresses. When you execute the request

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=24.8369%2C67.0334&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

you are getting back a nearest street address as shown in my screenshot

[image]

You can check it yourself using the Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D24.8369%252C67.0334

In order to search businesses you have to use [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) nearby search. If I search nearby places for given location and rank results by distance

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=24.8369%2C67.0334&rankby=distance&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

the first result in response is 'Pakistan State Oil (PSO) Head Office' (place ID ChIJeaL2ccU9sz4ReG88iRu5rNI)

[image]

I hope this helps!